# Doesn't rise native .net exception after fluentassertion exeption

Tags: c#, exception

If I use this code only `AssertionException` raises:

```
using (new AssertionScope())
{
    AssertionScope.Current.FailWith("AssertionException");
    throw new Exception("Exception");
}
```

How I can catch .net exception?

Comment: do you just want to catch the ex?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: Only one exception can be "active" at a time. If `AssertionException` is thrown, the `throw new...` statement is never executed.